# Objective-C — Posting to FB and Twitter using the apps

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook, twitter

I have an app that I want to integrate with Facebook and Twitter. I have been looking at the sharekit classes but unfortunately it seems that they need APPIDs which for other reasons I can't use. So is it possible to share a link using the Facebook app (if the user has the app installed). Maybe add some scheme like fblink://

The same question goes for Twitter. I know that with iOS SDK 5 there is built in support for Twitter but I want to be able to support iOS 4 users for awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer here: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook